# Android app doesn't finish launching in debug mode in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Debugging used to work, but now the screen stays black and the app doesn't finish launching, until there is timeout:

[image]

The debug window looks strange:

[image]

Restarting Eclipse, the device or the Windows machine doesn't help.

Comment: is it for specific code or general problem

Comment: It's specific. Debugging with another small app with the same build target works.

Comment: The threads in the debug window show up at first. One by one they change to <not responding>.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the debugger did reach 'Application.onCeate()' so I could step through the code and find the part that stalled the process.